# COnfigurar salto d elinea en v-list-item-title en Vue2

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

Cordial saludo.

Estoy aprendiendo Vue  Vuetify, tengo un inconveniente y es que los datos que traigo de la BD, información de un usuario, algunos de esto son demasiado largos.

El nombre del area del individuo es el más extenso, útilizo un v-list-title para mostrar este dato

```
<v-list-item-title v-html="usuario.nombre"></v-list-item-title>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo hago para qe en estos casos este dato haga un salto de línea?

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En lugar de `v-list-item-item` puedes usar `v-text-area` este lo hace por defecto.

```
<v-text-area class="title" v-html="usuario.nombre">                  
</v-text-area>
```

Comment: Excelente, gracias